# Am I creating this grid properly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create an app that (for now) looks through your camera roll and displays your images in a grid. I managed to get a single image to display initially, but when I tried to dynamically create grid rows, no images displayed. Can someone point out what I might be doing incorrectly and how to do this properly? I'm brand new to C# programming and Windows Phone Development so I apologize for the amateur question.

```
public async void PrintInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            TextBlock.Text = "";
            IReadOnlyCollection<StorageFile> PicLib = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFilesAsync();
            IEnumerator<StorageFile> PicLibEnum = PicLib.GetEnumerator();
            Debug.WriteLine(PicLib.Count);
            int Count = 0;
            foreach (StorageFile Pic in PicLib)
            {
                if (Count % 3 == 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Creating new row..." + Count % 3);
                    MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                }
                Image imageblock = new Image();
                imageblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, Count % 3);
                imageblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, Count / 3);
                Debug.WriteLine(imageblock);
                TextBlock.Text += Pic.Path + "\n";
                IRandomAccessStream PicStream = await Pic.OpenReadAsync();
                BitmapImage Bmp = new BitmapImage();
                await Bmp.SetSourceAsync(PicStream);
                //Uri Uri = new Uri(Pic.Path, UriKind.Absolute);
                //Bmp.UriSource = Uri;
                imageblock.Source = Bmp;
                //break;
                Count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TextBlock.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you possibly able to debug the code and report back on where the flaws are happening or if there are any error / exceptions..? if so what line(s) are the errors happening..?

Comment: There are no errors or exceptions. The images are simply not appearing. Is there maybe a way to visually display the grids so I can see if they're being created or not? EDIT: So the rows ARE being created. The images are just not displaying.

Comment: what if you were to test this with out using await and async..? I think that perhaps you would need some sort of callback but I could be wrong

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start with that. Like I said, I'm completely new to C# and WP. Everything I've done so far is pretty much just snippets of code I've seen online and I've Frankensteined it together to try and make it work. It also seems all the file reads are asynchronous so I might have to use async and await.

Comment: I personally would try to do this in a winforms application first then once you get it working try converting your code over to use `await Task` type code / functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, <s>don't use:</s>

```
imageblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, Count % 3);
```

<s>And use instead</s> is equivalent to

```
Grid.SetColumn(imageblock, Count % 3);
```

and the second one looks more straightforward to use in my opinion :)

Second thing, dinamically adding new rows and columns is not a good idea: you'd have to update *all* the column and row indexes of all your images every time you <s>add a new row / column</s> delete an item from your collection.
Try using a ListView, bind the source to an observable collection and use an Horizontal WrapGrid inside the ListView.
Then simply create your own DataTemplate with an image, Bind its source to each element of your ObservableCollection and you're up :)

You'll be able to add new images without worrying about the layout and the Grid indexes.

EDIT: This is the general idea, in XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"                  
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Or as Rob Caplan said, you can use a GridView, the end result is almost the same.

Then in your Page.Resources part, something like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,0" Height="45" Width="45">
        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you have to create a class that implements INotyfyPropertyChanged, create an instance in your page constructor and assign it to your DataContext.

Inside that class, you'll have something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<ImageSource> _Source = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Source
{
    get
    {
        return this._Source;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._Source != value)
        {
            this._Source = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the ListView will get the source collection from that Property in your ViewModel, and since the Source Property is an ObservableColleciton, every time you add an item the ListView will be notified and it will update its layout :)

Comment: Should I be creating the ListView and WrapGrid programatically or through XAML?

Comment: Absolutely through XAML, give me a couple of minutes and I will edit my answer with a code example :)

Comment: Oh god thanks so much for that but it seems that this stuff is way over my head... I may have to go back and just start with a simpler project to understand the basics or just read up on what this stuff even means.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, I started coding on WP8 last year and my first app was basically a blank page with a single button: you pressed that and you got "Hello world" displayed on a TextBlock ahahahahahah

Comment: I've gotten that far at least :P Do you think you could provide me with the resources you used to learn WP8? Also did you know C# prior to WP8 development?

Comment: No, I learned C# and XAML together when studying WP8 development. Before that, I only knew how to write in C and Python since I studied those last year at university. I didn't use any resource in particular, I just read a *lot* of stuff on MSDN (you have every single class and API explained with code examples and stuff) and here on StackOverflow, the rest was just spending hours and hours coding untile I got better :)

Comment: Data binding to an ItemsControl is the right idea, but the details here are a bit off. A GridView is a more natural choice than a ListView with a customized panel, and disabling virtualization is a bad idea for a large collection. I also don't understand the very strong stance taken against setting columns and rows via SetValue (the two forms are equivalent except for style) or why dynamically adding rows & columns would require additional calculations (nothing if added at the end, and a new layout is required either way if added in the beginning or middle)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment :) You're right, you don't have to edit the previous idexes when adding a new element, I was thinking about removing them ahahahah As for the Grid.SetColumn part, I said that just because using the Grid method seemed more straightforward, even if they both do the same thing. As for the ListView instead of the GridView, I didn't know there were many differences between the two, I used a ListView as I imagined his images collection to be scrolled vertically. I'll have to do some research about the GrivView control :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason the Images don't show up is that you don't add them to the Grid. After setting up the images add them to the MainGrid's Children and your code should work

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(imageblock);
```

Other that that your code is fine, although more complicated than necessary. As Sergio suggests you can simplify this greatly via data binding. Data binding will let you keep the data and the presentation separate: you can keep a collection of your images in the code and describe how they appear in the Xaml.

If you create an ObservableCollection containing the BitmapImages from your camera roll you can then add to it as needed and the binding will automatically display the new images in the Xaml (the ObservableCollection implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.interop.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) magic to report when items are added or removed). You can also bind to multiple controls with different appearances. If you want just the images you can add them directly to the collection. More commonly you'll bind to a class with other data as well, for example you might include the image and its name.

In Xaml you'll use an ItemsControl to display the collection. Since you want a grid the GridView is a good choice. If you want a List with each item in its own row then a ListView would be better. You can set an ItemTemplate to control how the images appear:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>            
</GridView>
```

See [Data binding overview (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx) on MSDN for more details

Comment: Oh, now I understand why you said a GridView would be better :) I used a ListView with the Horizontal WrapGrid orientation so that it'd display the elements in the same way a GridView would, but I get that using a GridView from the beginning would be a better idea, thanks!